# how can i add a time to display an input button

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I made a login page and when you click on login it displays the progress. That's exactly what I want but sometimes it takes too much time to respond and login so I made a button to go back but it is displayed immediately when the progress is loading.

I want it to be displayed after 10 seconds - not immediately .

Comment: Have a look at setTimeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout` function:

```
setTimeout(function() { /*code here*/ }, 10000 /*time in milliseconds*/ );
```

Read more about it @ [`setTimeout` : MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

*As a side note I recommended pure js because jQuery increases load on the server*

Comment: the OP mentioned ten seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can try `delay` function

```
$('#button_id').delay(5000).fadeIn(10000);
```

And if you dont want jquery:

```
setTimeout(function() {  Yourcode here }, 10000 //time(milliseconds) );
```

Comment: I didn’t see a jQuery tag

Comment: @David Point taken. Edited my answer

Comment: What's the matter of telling him about jQuery when he donot want?

Comment: This question may be visited by more users in future. They may want to use JQuery. For OP i have made the edit